# Accessing the data with dot-syntax

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

The JSON:

```
{
    "count": 1,
    "rows": [
        {
            "user_id": "7",
            "lat": "48.452583",
            "lng": "-123.545052",
            "distance": "0.4852177729308128"
        }
    ]
}​
```

This comes into my `function(data)` and I'm trying to access `count` and then the `user_id` ..

```
downloadUrl(searchUrl, function(data) {
    alert( "Locations Found: " + data[0].count );
});
```

`data.count`, `data[0].count` ... don't work. And I'm drawing a blank as to how to access them.

Comment: `data.count` is correct. Are you sure you're receiving it as JSON? (Hint: you need `dataType: "json"`.)

Comment: Do you parse the JSON? If you use AJAX, set the dataType to json or else use $.parseJSON

Comment: I've added the function I'm using above.

Comment: @dcolumbus, use console.log(data,typeof(data)) and see what it prints in the console

Comment: @dcolumbus Maybe add the function code for downloadUrl? Also, is the searchUrl on your server? It could also be a Cross-Origin restriction.

Comment: I need to convert it from a string to an actual object. That's for pointing that out @AnkurMittal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your `data` is string (not data-type:json) then you need to parse it as follows

```
var obj=$.parseJSON(data);
```

Then use

```
obj.count;
obj.rows[0].user_id;
```

Comment: you can use `JSON.parse()` if you don't use Jquery

Comment: Yes but `jQuery` tag is used in the question so I answered as jQuery.

Comment: @AnkurMittal, JSON.parse() is not cross browser supported

Comment: @Jashwant, so what is the safest bet? Should I use jQuery?

Comment: ya it is not supported in IE6,7 and didn't saw jquery tag, my mistake

Comment: i think OP can use `var obj = JSON && JSON.parse(data) || $.parseJSON(data);`, it will be faster

Comment: @jbabey, It's `jQuery` related.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
data = {"count":1,"rows":[{"user_id":"7","lat":"48.452583","lng":"-123.545052","distance":"0.4852177729308128"}]}
data.count
data.rows[0].user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Is data really an Object or just a string. You can debug type with most browser's console by doing console.log(typeof data) or alternatively alert(typeof data).